# ObjectDataSource, CustomValidators and DataBinding

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an ObjectDataSource that is bound to a GridView. The object accepts a parameter from a TextBox. The problem I have is when I use a CustomerValidator with a ServerValidate event, the  ObjectDataSource would still attempt to perform a DataBind despite the fact the the customer validator has returned false.

The following is the code in the ASPX page.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="sittingDate" runat="server" />
<asp:CustomValidator ID="DateValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="sittingDate" OnServerValidate="DateValidator_ServerValidate" />
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="BatchDataSource" runat="server" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}"
        SelectMethod="GetOrCreateSittingBatch" TypeName="BatchBLL" OnSelected="BatchDataSource_Selected" OnSelecting="BatchDataSource_Selecting">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="sittingDate" Name="batchDate" PropertyName="Text"
                Type="DateTime" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
<asp:GridView ID="BatchGridView" runat="server" DataSourceID="BatchDataSource">
```

In the Custom Validator I have

```
protected void DateValidator_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
        //Ensure that the entered data is a date.
        string input = args.Value;

        DateTime result;
        args.IsValid = DateTime.TryParse(input.TrimEnd(), out result);
}
```

How do I stop the ObjectDataSource from data binding when validation has failed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
void BatchDataSource_Selecting(object sender, ObjectDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
{
    if(!Page.IsValid)
        e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot. However in my situation since I was doing a type conversion check, I needed to modify the select parameter from 
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="sittingDate" Type="DateTime" />
to 
   <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="sittingDate" Type="String" /> 

otherwise when invalid data was entered, a type exception was being thrown before the BatchDataSource_Selecting event was being called.

Answer (score 0):

Try performing Page.Validate and then check if the Page.IsValid to prevent the data binding like:

```
this.Page.Validate();
if (this.Page.IsValid)
{
   ...
}
```

You can add this to your `Page_Load` event or in the perhaps in your ObjectDataSource's `OnDataBinding` event to prevent the data binding if the Page.IsValid is false.

Comment: How is data binding prevented in the ObjectDataSource's DataBinding event? There is only EventArgs without a .Cancel property.